# LDAP Bulk Provisioning

Tags: ldap

Need to know what best practices i need to follow for LDAP Bulk Provisioning with respect to following parameter's

1. Ldap connection
2. Max Parallel Connection allowed
3. RAM if provisioning client to be run locally/remotely

Regards,
vishal

Answer (score 0):

Use connection pooling if possible. Maximum number of simultaneous connections and RAM are server-hardware specific. For general discussion of LDAP praxis see ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).